# get "DeviceId" and display it in textview

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I'm trying to get phone serial number and show it in text view..
so this is my code:

```
    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    mngr.getDeviceId();

    String aa;
    aa.setText(mngr);


    TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneidtxtview);
    tt.setText(aa);
```

but I get this error:

> The method setText(TelephonyManager) is undefined for the type String

i have checked [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29) page and i know the return of the top code is "string"... so what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aa` is the object of class String. It has no method called `setText()`.
This is what you've to do :

Declare this permission in the manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Now get DeviceId() in this way :

```
    String identifier = null;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (tm != null)
        identifier = tm.getDeviceId();
    if (identifier == null || identifier .length() == 0)
        identifier = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Set the identifier as text of TextView tt

```
TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneidtxtview);
tt.setText(identifier);
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I'm getting 2 error: "context cannot be resolved" & "activity cannot be resolved" in lines 2&6

Comment: Try with the updated code and don't forget to chose the right answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Your have to implement this on your Activity

```
@SuppressLint({"MissingPermission", "HardwareIds"})
```

or this permission on your Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

This will work on your device, but This will not be approved by Google Playstore if you are planning this to upload on playstore, unless your App is a System App, you are not allowed to use this if your App is normal app. Your code should be like this.

```
@SuppressLint({"MissingPermission", "HardwareIds"})
String identifier = null;
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephonyManager != null){
        identifier = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    }
    if (identifier == null || identifier.length() == 0){
        identifier = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }

    mTextView.setText(identifier);
```